# obj.hasOwnProperty always returns false even after property created

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my Vue application, I have an array of stocks:

```
stocks : [
    {'name' : 'Tesla', 'price' : 800},
    {'name' : 'Microsoft', 'price' : 300},
]
```

I also have a conditional element that looks like this:

```
<template v-for="stock in stocks">
    <div>{{ stock.name }}</div>
    <div v-if="stock.hasOwnProperty('test')">test</div>
</template>
```

I have a method that sets the test property for a stock. For example:

```
this.stocks[0].test = true;
```

If, under this statement, I `console.log(this.stocks)` I see the `test` property for the first `stock`. But, in the template, the element that is supposed to show up when a `stock` has this property still doesn't show up. Why is this and how can I achieve showing/hiding stock elements dynamically based on whether they have the `test` property?

Comment: Vue doesn't detect the change; you have to a) use `this.$forceUpdate();` or b) use a key for the list items that changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue (2, anyway) [cannot detect property addition or removal](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/change-detection.html#declaring-reactive-properties).

You should declare the `test` property within `stocks`, so that it's there from the beginning:

```
stocks : [
    {'name' : 'Tesla', 'price' : 800, test: false },
    {'name' : 'Microsoft', 'price' : 300, test: false },
]
```

Then it'll be reactive and you can show/hide your element based on the value of `test`.